How to connect two 32" TVs from graphics card
I have a Nvidia Geforce GTX1050 with DVI and HDMI ports. My MSI motherboard has DVI, VGA and DisplayPort.
The problem is when I connect one 32" TV to the graphics card it works fine but when I connect the other 32" TV to the other port in the graphics card the taskbar starts flickering. Both TVs have 1366×768 resolution.
Please help to connect 3 32" TV to PC using multi-monitor support.

Are these TVs the only displays connected to your computer, or is there a monitor connected also, and if so, what resolution is that monitor? Also, does it matter which of the ports you have connected the TVs to? I presume you're using HDMI for on, but may be using an adapter for the others.

Is the display driver up to date? As at this moment, that is version 560.94 WHQL.

"Please help to connect 3 32" TV" - Impossible; Your hardware does not support this configuration. Do you want to connect two 32" TVs or three 32" TVs. The title of your question suggests it's only two.
